# Auto form filler for NYC DOE health screening

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, bots

I am new to programming.
I need to do health screening for my job at NYC DOE school. It is mundane and repetitive task. So I thought it would saving me time if I made a form filler bot for it and also learn more about programming. so I am using python and selenium in pycharm. i am running the program but it's not working on the health screening website. when I used similar format on google forum it worked. so what am I doing wrong? or is it a build in bot protection website? Here is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

web = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/path/chromedriver.exe')
#web.get('https://forms.gle/4WfVvWdZSi31f5DB9')
web.get('https://healthscreening.schools.nyc/?type=G#')

web.set_page_load_timeout(5)


Email = "EMAILTEST@gmail.com"
School = "//*[@id='guest_identity_form']/div[2]/div[14]/span/span/span[1]/div"
Floor = ""
LastName = "DOE"
FirstName = "JOHN"

first = web.find_element_by_id('guest_first_name')
last = web.find_element_by_id('guest_last_name')
GYbutton = web.find_element_by_id('guest_isNonDOE')
school = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="guest_identity_form"]/div[2]/div[14]/span/span/span[1]/div')

GYbutton.click()
first.send_keys(FirstName)
last.send_keys(LastName)
school.click()
```

Thanks

Comment: what is not working? what error you are getting?

Comment: it's not entering the values , such as the name and etc. nor clicking the button.

Comment: I'd suspect this line: GYbutton.click() .... could be causing everything to go stale.... do that first... then find the form elements.  Good to use explicit webdriverwaits throughout... but especially after that first click.  I would also leave page load timeout at default (don't set it).  Never know when the internet's gonna get a little clogged up and slow a page load.